# Emulating Excel's YearFrac in C#

Tags: c#, excel

How can I get the same results of the [Excel YearFrac function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/yearfrac-HP005209344.aspx) in my C# application?

> Calculates the fraction of the year represented by the number of whole days between two dates (the start_date and the end_date). Use the YEARFRAC worksheet function to identify the proportion of a whole year's benefits or obligations to assign to a specific term.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a good [snippet](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/d7df9ac9-cc5f-49d2-91ef-1fe5fb0790d9).

The algorithm for the YearFrac function is in fact very complex. Maybe [this article](http://www.dwheeler.com/yearfrac/excel-ooxml-yearfrac.pdf) can provide you with more details.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Excel's functionality directly to calculate `YearFrac`. Microsoft says [you are not supposed to use it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.iworksheetfunction%28v=office.11%29.aspx), but it works very well. If you need a 100% compatibility with Excel, this solution is hard to beat. You need to add to your project a reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` in order for this code to compile.

```
static void Main() {
    var excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorksheetFunction wsf = excel.WorksheetFunction;
    var start = new DateTime(1999, 11, 1);
    var end = new DateTime(1999, 1, 11);
    for (var basis = 0; basis != 5; basis++) {
        Console.WriteLine(wsf.YearFrac(start, end, basis));
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree it's the most accurate solution but I don't like to reference the Interop libraries because I need the YearFrac function on a web application on IIS and I don't want Excel installed on it.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of YEARFRAC is YEARFRAC(Date startDate, Date endDate, int convention). The method to calculate the YEARFRAC depends on the convention.

For convention = 2, YEARFRAC will calculate the YEARFRAC using ACT/360 method. An implementation of the ACT/360 can be found at [svn.finmath.net](http://svn.finmath.net/finmath%20lib/trunk/src/main/java/net/finmath/time/daycount/), specifically [DayCountConvention_ACT_360.java](http://svn.finmath.net/finmath%20lib/trunk/src/main/java/net/finmath/time/daycount/DayCountConvention_ACT_360.java)

For convention = 3, YEARFRAC will calculate the YEARFRAC using ACT/365 method. An implementation of the ACT/365 can be found at [svn.finmath.net](http://svn.finmath.net/finmath%20lib/trunk/src/main/java/net/finmath/time/daycount/), specifically 
[DayCountConvention_ACT_365.java](http://svn.finmath.net/finmath%20lib/trunk/src/main/java/net/finmath/time/daycount/DayCountConvention_ACT_365.java)

For convention = 4, YEARFRAC will calculate the YEARFRAC using 30E/360 method. An implementation of the 30E/360 can be found at [svn.finmath.net](http://svn.finmath.net/finmath%20lib/trunk/src/main/java/net/finmath/time/daycount/), specifically [DayCountConvention_30E_360.java](http://svn.finmath.net/finmath%20lib/trunk/src/main/java/net/finmath/time/daycount/DayCountConvention_30E_360.java)

For convention = 1, the documentation claims that YEARFRAC is calculate using ACT/ACT convention. However, there are a multiple versions of ACT/ACT and I believe the standard for many financial products is ACT/ACT ISDA. I found that YEARFRAC differs by a small amount from the ACT/ACT IDSA convention! An implementation of the ACT/ACT IDSA can be found at [DayCountConvention_ACT_ACT_ISDA.java](http://svn.finmath.net/finmath%20lib/trunk/src/main/java/net/finmath/time/daycount/DayCountConvention_ACT_ACT_ISDA.java)

I haven't checked the other act/act versions yet, but I would not rely on an emulation of YEARFRAC ACT/ACT, when it is not clear what kind of method they implement...

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest:

```
    public static double Yearfrac(DateTime startDate,DateTime endDate,DayCount daycount=DayCount.ActAct)
    {
        var nbDaysInPeriod = (double)(endDate - startDate).Days;

        switch(daycount)
        {
            case (DayCount.Act360):
                return nbDaysInPeriod / (double)360;
            case (DayCount.Act365):
                return nbDaysInPeriod / (double)365;
            case (DayCount.ActAct):
                return GetActAct(startDate,endDate);
            case (DayCount.Days360):
                var result = (endDate.Year - startDate.Year) * 360.0 + (endDate.Month - startDate.Month) * 30.0 + (Math.Min(endDate.Day, 30.0) - Math.Min(startDate.Day, 30.0));
                return result/360;
            default:
                return nbDaysInPeriod / (double)365;
        }
    }

    public static double GetActAct(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        // Reproduce Excel Yearfrac as per http://www.dwheeler.com/yearfrac/excel-ooxml-yearfrac.pdf
        var nbDaysInPeriod = (double)(endDate - startDate).Days;
        if(startDate.Year==endDate.Year || (endDate.Year-1==startDate.Year&&(startDate.Month>endDate.Month||startDate.Month==endDate.Month&&(startDate.Day>=endDate.Day))))
        {
            var den =  365.0;
            if (startDate.Year == endDate.Year && DateTime.IsLeapYear(startDate.Year))
            {
                den++;
            }
            else
            {

                if (endDate.Day == 29 && endDate.Month == 2)
                {
                    den++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(startDate.Year))
                    {
                        var feb = new DateTime(startDate.Year, 2, 29);
                        if (startDate<=feb && feb<=endDate) den++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(endDate.Year))
                        {
                            var feb = new DateTime(endDate.Year, 2, 29);
                            if (startDate <= feb && feb <= endDate) den++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var nbYears = endDate.Year - startDate.Year+1;
            var den = nbYears * 365.0;
            for (var i=0;i<nbYears;i++)
            {
                if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(startDate.Year + i)) den++;
            }
            den /= nbYears;
            return nbDaysInPeriod / den;
        }
        return nbDaysInPeriod / 365.0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an exact YEARFRAC which measures to the day (so no need to specify any day-count convention) and gives a negative for periods in the past try this date extension...

```
 public static double YearFrac(this DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        startDate = DateTime.Parse(startDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
        endDate = DateTime.Parse(endDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if (startDate == endDate)
            return 0.0;
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        double reverse = 1.0;
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if (startDate > endDate)
        {
            var ed = endDate;
            endDate = startDate;
            startDate = ed;
            reverse = -1.0;
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        int y1 = startDate.Year;
        int y2 = endDate.Year;
        int m1 = startDate.Month;
        int m2 = endDate.Month;
        int d1 = startDate.Day;
        int d2 = endDate.Day;
        int diy = startDate.DaysInYear();
        int days = (endDate - startDate).Days;
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if (y1 == y2)
        {
            return (double)days / (double)diy * reverse;
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        int wholeyears = y2 - y1 - 1;
        DateTime lastDateA = ValidDate(y2 - 1, m2, d2);
        DateTime lastDateB = ValidDate(y2 - 1, m1, d1);
        int period1 = (endDate - lastDateA).Days;
        int period2 = (endDate - lastDateB).Days;
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if (m1 > m2 || (m1 == m2 && d1 > d2))
        {
            return ((double)wholeyears + (double)period2 / (double)period1) * reverse;
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        DateTime lastDateC = ValidDate(y2, m1, d1);
        int period3 = (endDate - lastDateC).Days;
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        return ((double)wholeyears + 1.0 + (double)period3 / (double)period1) * reverse;
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }
    public static DateTime ValidDate(int y, int m, int d)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(y, m, d);
            return dt1;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            try
            {
                if (d == 29 && m == 2)
                {
                    return new DateTime(y, 3, 1);
                }
                return new DateTime(y, m, d);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
    public static int DaysInYear(this DateTime date)
    {
        int year = date.Year;

        DateTime d1 = DateTime.Parse("01-Jan-" + year.ToString());
        DateTime d2 = DateTime.Parse("01-Jan-" + (year + 1).ToString());
        int diy = (d2 - d1).Days;
        return diy;
    }
```